# Fetching valid record in unix on temporary basis?

Tags: shell, csv, unix, text

I have an file like this:

```
EMP Ename Sal Comm
101 Ravi $800 500
102 Ram $1000 40
103 Shyam $@400 50
```

I want to convert it to this form:

```
EMP Ename Sal  Comm
101 Ravi  800  500
102 Ram   1000 40
103 Shyam 400  50
```

The file is tab delimited. I've tried with awk, but unfortunately I couldn't remove the "`$@`" part from the `Sal` column.

Comment: Take a look the the `sed` and the `awk` utility. Both are well documented, both inline and in their man mages: `man sed` and `man awk`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
sed -e 's/\$//g' -e 's/\@//g' file > newFile
```

Slightly confused about what you mean about not needing it permanently.

Alternatively, in vi:

```
:%s/\$//g'
:%s/\@//g'
```

If you want to modify a file inside a vi session

Comment: Thanks I found an easy alternative 

cut -f 3 <filename> | tr -d '$@'